# Django Deploying on Alwaysdata

Tags: python, django

I readed the [deploying django app](http://wiki.alwaysdata.com/wiki/Deploying_a_Django_App) from Alwaysdata and I have a problem.

We I run `bash django.fcgi`, terminal shows :

```
import: unable to open X server `' @ import.c/ImportImageCommand/367.
django.fcgi: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
django.fcgi: line 5: `PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))'
```

I made all they said but I can't fix that. I run on Django 1.5.

```
- mymodule
- mysite
... __init__.py
... settings.py
... urls.py
.. wsgi.py
- public
... django.fcgi
... .htaccess
... static
... media
- manage.py
- statics
- templates
- __init__.py
```

This is `django.fcgi` and `.htaccess` :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_DIR)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR))

PROJECT_NAME = PROJECT_DIR.split('/')[-1]
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

---

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ django.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Where is my problem ? I encoded my django.fcgi file in Unicode BOM, like [here](http://forum.alwaysdata.com/viewtopic.php?id=2751) but no results. Have you any idea ?
Thank you...

EDIT: And well, my website doesn't work : 500 Internal Server Error.

Server configuration : Apache, Python 2.6, Django 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not supposed to run that file that way. Despite having the shebang line at the beginning, the file should be interpreted as a shell script (bash) and not a python script, hence the "import" error (`import` seems to be an ImageMagick command which makes something like a screenshot).

So the correct way to run that file would one of those

```
bash -c "./django.fcgi" # file must have execution permission
python django.fcgi
./django.fcgi           # also
```

The 500 error can be debugged either turning `DEBUG=True` on `settings.py` or reading the logs, if your application is configured to log somewhere.

Edit:

Regarding the import error, I think the right configuration is

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "mysite.settings"
```

The way you have it Django is trying to load `public/settings.py` which fails. More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/).

If that doesn't work try to specify the full path to settings.py:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "mysite", "settings")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `ImportError: Could not import settings '/nfs/http10/myfootactu/www/myfootactu/settings' (Is it on sys.path?): Import by filename is not supported. `. I tried a lot of combinaisons to fix that in my `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']` variable but... nothing to do. 

For that, I ran `python django.fcgi`

Comment: If I turn `DEBUG = True`, any can see urls, parameters, etc. and I just want replace debug by 404 file. I made some searchs but nothing on this topic...

Comment: Yes, in a production site that must be always off. I pointed that out because I thought this was just a "test" website. To debug in that occasion you can check the apache logs. Also `runfastcgi` seems to accept a `errlog` parameter: see [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/servers/fastcgi.py).